# Cloudant group records

Tags: group-by, cloudant

I have a record of type:
{
"field1":"abcd",
"field2":"abcd1",
"field3": {
    "id": "some_id"
 },
"field4":"abcd3",
"field5":"abcd4",
"field6":"abcd5"
}

How can I get a list of all records grouped by field3.id

PS: I want the entire record to be returned and not just count.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view emitting field3.id as the key:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.field3 && doc.field3.id) {
        emit(doc.field3.id, null);
    }
}
```

The view groups entries with the same key. Now query the view with the parameter include_docs=true to also get the full record.